# Prove equation $4xy - x - y = z^2$ has no answers in natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do I show that the diophantine equation $4xy - x - y = z^2$ has no solution save for $x = y = z = 0$?

Can you offer a hint?

Comment: So what about $x=y=z=0$? Maybe this is the exception?

Comment: [Here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1117221_4xy__x__y__z2_prove_there_are_no_z_solutions) is already a solution.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1055882_the_decomposition_of_the_square   https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049059__

Comment: Does this proof work? $(4y-1)x-y=z^2 \Longrightarrow z^2 \equiv -y \mod{4y-1} \equiv 3y-1 \mod{4y-1}$ $\Longrightarrow 3y-1 \equiv (z \mod{4y-1})^2 \mod{4y-1}
\Longrightarrow z \equiv \sqrt{3y-1} \mod{4y-1}$. Since $3y-1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ it can't be a perfect square.

Answer (score 3):

That implies
$$16xy-4x-4y+1=1+4z^2$$
that is
$$(4x-1)(4y-1)=1+4z^2.$$
There is a famous theorem to the effect that for a prime $p\equiv3\pmod 4$, the congruence $t^2\equiv-1\pmod p$ is insoluble.

Comment: Could you put a link or a proof of the last statement for reference? All you would need is to show $(2n)^2$ and $(2n+1)^2$ cannot equal $3\bmod4$.